# How to Set a color in a titleForHeaderInSection? -swift

Tags: swift, tableview

I have two sections in my tableview and I want to set a different colour for different sectionHeaders of the tableView, how can I do that?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String! {
    if (section == 0) {
        return "Item1"
    }
    if (section == 1) {
        return "Item2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in the same way as in Objective-C: providing a custom header with a label and change it's text color

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView! {
    var label : UILabel = UILabel()
    if(section == 0){
        label.text = "Item1"
    } else if (section == 1){
        label.textColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        label.text = "Item2"
    }
    return label
}
```

Comment: do i have to put an if statement saying (section == 1) then write the code you just provided??

Comment: Hey i read and implemented the code but i don't see why in this func we need to use a label. if what I'm trying to change is the color in my headerinsection not the text...   or am i wrong?

Comment: a string knowns nothing about how to display itself. tat is the task of a label.

Comment: is it possible to change the background color in a header??

Comment: would you mind showing me how? i type in HeaderView.setbackgroundColor and its wrong...

Answer (score 4):

Swift 5.1

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if section == 0 {
        return "Section 1"
    } else {
        return "Section 2"
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let label = UILabel()

    if section == 0 {
        label.text = "Sectionn 1"
    } else {
        label.text = "Section 2"
    }

    return label

}
```

and don't forget to set height for the view

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}
```